# Satan being allowed in the new Paradise on Earth

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, jehovahs-witnesses

I recall reading a scripture from the Bible with two JW's that said in the new Paradise Satan would be allowed. I questioned that with them and they smiled and said "yes".
Can you tell me in what book and verse of the Bible it says this?

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah’s Witnesses teach that after Armageddon Satan and his demons are thrown into the abyss (a state of inactivity)and a 1000 year long judgment day will begin. 
During this time earth will be made a paradise, mankind will attain to perfection, the dead will be resurrected  all mankind will be judged.
A brief description of judgement day can be found [here](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-teach/what-is-judgment-day-1000-year-reign/)

At the end of the 1000 years a final testing described as taking a little while will take place when Satan is released and allowed to try to mislead mankind on final time.

The scripture that you are looking for is 
Revelation 20:3 it reads from the new world translation :

> And he hurled him into the abyss and shut it and sealed it over him, so that he would not mislead the nations anymore until the 1,000 years were ended. After this he must be released for a little while.

And vs 7&8 read:

> Now as soon as the 1,000 years have ended, Satan will be released from his prison, 8  and he will go out to mislead those nations in the four corners of the earth, Gog and Maʹgog, to gather them together for the war. The number of these is as the sand of the sea.

Good news is this time of testing is brief and Satan is then eternally destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have misunderstood what the Witnesses said about Satan being allowed in the new paradise earth.  **Revelation 20:1-3** describes how an angel comes down from heaven and, with God’s authority, binds Satan in chains and throws him into the Abyss where he is locked up for the duration of the Millennium.

**Revelation 20:7-10** then describes how Satan is released at the end of the thousand years to deceive the nations and gather them for the final battle against God’s people.  They surround the camp of God’s people, the city he loves, but fire comes down from heaven and destroys them. Satan and all who follow him are defeated and Satan is then hurled into the lake of burning sulphur where the beast and the false prophet are, where they will be tormented day and night for ever and ever.

Satan will be released from the Abyss for a short while at the end of the Millennium, only to be utterly and permanently defeated.  Here is a short extract from the Watchtower 15 November 2004 Questions from Readers: Where will the demons be during the Thousand Year Reign of Christ?

> Concerning Satan’s final destiny, the Bible says: “The Devil who was misleading them was hurled into the lake of fire and sulphur, where both the wild beast and the false prophet already were; and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.” (Revelation 20:10)...  The Bible refers to “the everlasting fire prepared for the Devil and his angels.” (Matthew 25:41) Satan and his demons will be thrown into the same “lake of fire and sulphur” as the wild beast and the false prophet in that they too will be destroyed forever.

Here is another extract from the Jehovah’s Witness publication God’s Kingdom Rules (2014 Chapter 22, p. 237):

> After the Millennium there will be a final test when “Satan is released from his abyss of inactivity.  Thereafter, Christ will finally crush that vile serpent and all his supporters (Revelation 20:3-10).

There is nothing in the Bible to suggest that Satan will be allowed access to the Earth during the Millennial reign of Christ Jesus, only that he will be released from the Abyss for a short while at the end of the thousand years, when he and all who support him will be utterly defeated.